# How to save file with changed encoding without modifying its content in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```bsh
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $Encoding = 'UTF8',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $Types= @('*.json', '*.ps1')
)

Get-ChildItem $Source\* -Recurse -Include $Types| ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Fullname
    try {
        $content = ($_ | Get-Content)
        $content | Out-File $name -Encoding $Encoding -Force | Out-Null
    } catch {
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```

How should I change it to have only encoding of the files changed without appending an empty line at the end of the file (in case file hasn't an empty line) and without removing the ending line (if it has one). In other words, I just want to change encoding of files in some path without changing the content.

Comment: AFAIK `Out-File` always adds a line break/new line at the end. You could try `Set-Content` instead.

Comment: @Olaf, By default `Set-Content` also appends a new line at the end

Comment: OK. I didn't test that before. Sorry. But what's actually the issue with this behaviour? An empty line at the end should not be a problem for any json or ps1 file. ;-)

Comment: It's not a problem, but I just need that simple script to regenerate whole git repository to have only one encoding :) and you know how it can look like on a git ;) getting 5k changes instead of 100

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem here is changed script:

```bsh
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $Encoding = 'UTF8',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $Types= @('*.json', '*.ps1')
)

Get-ChildItem $Source\* -Recurse -Include $Types| ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Fullname
    try {
        $content = ($_ | Get-Content -Raw)
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($name, $content, [Text.Encoding]::$Encoding)
    } catch {
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```